# Given an object that can have 1 of 4 attributes, how many ways can n objects be arranged so that the attributes are symmetrical?

Tags: combinatorics

I was given this problem in my math lecture and I'm lost on how to approach it. I know that having less than three objects allows 4 different symmetrical arrangements:

1 object:
A
B
C
D

2 objects:
AA
BB
CC
DD

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here in a mathematical way. Any help on how I can proceed?

Thanks

Comment: What type of symmetry? Reflection left-to-right?

Comment: @kccu Essentially it should be that the way it's read forward is the way it's read backwards. Like for 5 objects this would be a symmetrical arrangement: ABCBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suppose the number of objects is even, so $n=2k$ for some integer $k$. Let $A_i$ denote the attribute of the $i$th object. Then the attributes of the list of $n$ objects are:
$$A_1A_2\cdots A_kA_{k+1}\cdots A_{2k-1}A_{2k}.$$
For this to be symmetric, we must have $A_1=A_{2k}$, $A_2=A_{2k-1}$, etc. So the list of attributes can be written as:
$$A_1A_2\cdots A_kA_k \cdots A_2A_1.$$
How many ways are there to choose these attributes?

If $n$ is odd, then the attributes don't all pair up with another one when you do the reflection. In particular, if there are $2k+1$ objects, then the $k+1$st does not move when you reflect the others. So the list of attributes looks like:
$$A_1A_2\cdots A_kA_{k+1}A_k\cdots A_2A_1.$$
How many ways are there to choose these attributes?

Comment: In the case where n is even, until we get to the the value (i/2) we have 4 ways to choose the attributes. So would it be 4^{n/2} ways to choose the attributes?

Comment: That's right when $n$ is even.

Comment: In the case where n is odd, until we get to the the value ((i + 1)/2) we have 4 ways to choose the attributes. So would it be 4^{(n + 1)/2} ways to choose the attributes.

Comment: Thanks for help! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yep, you got it.